# Неправильно работает ЧПУ opencart 2.3

Tags: opencart2.0

При установке ЧПУ: главная,и категория отображаются нормально, а вот подкатегории и товары отображаются без стилей.
тоесть эти урлы показываются отлично

```
site.com
site.com/category
```

а такие пооказываются без стилей

```
site.com/category/sub-category
site.com/category/sub-category/product
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пропишите до стилей корневые пути вместо относительных.

Вот так правильно:

```
/css/styles.css
```

Вот так - работать не будет:

```
css/styles.css
```

Comment: ТочнЯк, Спасибо большое.